# jQuery automatic load after window location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page use Jquery `load();`

when user **click** 'my post' button, it will `load('my_post.php');`(**It only show when user click it**)

I have another delete button, it will send to php file and delete the post from database

after deleted, it will `window.location` back to the same page.

However I need to auto `load 'my post'` after `window.location`. So user can see what they deleted the post without click the button and load it again.

something like this

```
echo "
<script>           
$(location).attr('href', 'my_account.php', 
    function(){
        $('#box').load('my_post.php');
    }
);      
</script>       
";
```

Comment: tell next page to load the file

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: i'm thinking to use $_GET, if ($_GET=='whatever'){load();} but I'm not sure is any better way or not

Comment: The question is, I want to tell next page to do someting after I window location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tell a previous page to do something in the next page. That is just impossible.

You can do something when the next page loads or pass a parameter like my_account.php?x=1 and only load the `$(document).ready(function() {` when the `$_GET["x"]` has been passed.

TLDR: You can't do it like you want to do it.

Comment: ya thats why im thinking to pass get to next page. lol, thx for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a meta tag that gets populated on your page every time it's loaded, and passed with the header, or in params, then you can make a

PHP:

```
<meta name="page_triggers" content="<?= $_GET['page_triggers'] ?>">
```

Jquery:

```
page = Array();
$(function(){
  page_triggers = $('meta[name="page_triggers"]').attr('content').split(" ");
  $.each(page_triggers, function(page_trigger){
    page[page_trigger]();
  });
}
page['my_awesome_trigger'] = function(){
   do_some_awesome_stuff();
}
```

Or open a socket somehow.